# Byte-Range not in request header for HTML5 audio

Tags: apache, google-chrome, audio-streaming, html5-audio

I am streaming a *.mp3 file through read_file.php , requested by listen.php.

read_file.php - handles Byte-Ranges correctly, and serves up the correct byte-range of the file with correct headres.

listen.php - contains an HTML5 Audio element with the read_file.php?id=XX as the src

XX.mp3 - A large mp3 file I hope to serve in chunks.

The requests triggered by HTML5 Audio element do not seem to always send the Requested byte-range in the request header.  On First load, the header contains "Byte-Range: 0-".  The response header sees this, and serves up a chunk of the file.

The result being:

Seek ahead works as expected.  Seek back either (1) is canceled, or (2) Starts back at the beggining of the file, depending on how I choose the logic in read_file.php to deal with a NULL byte-range.

Any pointers/thoughts, or dare i say it ... answers?

Related Chrome Error: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2pBjnF00

Comment: Can you paste the response headers?

Comment: When it works (just letting it play, no seeking) this is the returned header: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=v2KvXTMX

Comment: Well, one thing I notice is that your `Content-Range` header is off by 1. `bytes 0-17178539/17178539` The number following the hyphen is the last **index** of the byte range. It should be `17178538`.

Comment: you are right :)  actually, it's turning into a couple errors (apache didn't have mod_headers enabled, d'oh).  Now it looks like i'm just dealing with running our of memory when reading the file.

Comment: Headers are good, memory load is fine (reading in chunks), not throwing errors/warnings, but it seems like chrome is making a bogus request when you seek back towards the beggining too fast.  There's no response, and it just craps out :/

Comment: The only things I can think of that might be causing issues are possibly the empty `Pragma` header or the 1981 `Expires` header. Chrome probably attempts to read from cache when you seek back but chokes on one of those directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, here are the headers in the final (working) form:

```
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
header('Cache-Control: '); //blank for IE
header('Pragma: ');   // blank for IE
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length:'.$length);
header("Content-Range: bytes $begin-".$end."/$length");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Last-Modified: $time");

header('Connection: close');
```